# Mongoid - Detect if there are results on the next page

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid6

Using Mongoid, how can I check if given the `limit/results_per_page` options there is a next page ?

Suppose my scope is

```
MyCollection.page(@page).per(@per)
```

Calling `.count` will compute the total number of results across all pages. But how do I detect if the current page is full/empty ? Or better if the next page is empty ? Do I have to resolve the scope by calling something like `to_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calling `.count` will compute the total number of results across all pages.

Yes. And you know `@page` and `@per`. That's all you need. As long as `@page * @per` is less than `count`, you have (at least one) next page. (*assuming pages start with 1 and not 0*)

Example:

We have 57 elements and our page size is 20.

```
@page    @per   displaying   @page*@per  count  have next page?
  1       20      1 - 20        20         57         yes
  2       20      21 - 40       40         57         yes
  3       20      41 - 57       60         57         no
```